# How to display customizable option in magento 2 product page

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have added custom options for products referring https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

How can i display these options on product page in magento 2?
Any idea?

Comment: you want to show custom options in product page ???

Comment: Yes. How can the customer select values from this. they are not displayed on product page by default?

Comment: you go to admin panel `catalog > Products > click add product button >  Search Customizable Options > click the add option` after clear cache